# Getting exception when retrieving database value with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and wanted to do a sql query (using entity framework 5) when I got System.ArgumentNullException for:

STACK TRACE:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
  Source=System.Core
  ParamName=source
  StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Model.RavenDB.ThreadProvider_Raven.Get(Eid item, Rid forum) in c:\Users\fm\Desktop\121219scraper-mssql\Model.RavenDB\ThreadProvider_Raven.cs:line 52
   at Model.RavenDB.ThreadProvider_Raven.Exsist(Eid item, Rid forum, Nullable`1& out_Item) in c:\Users\fm\Desktop\121219scraper-mssql\Model.RavenDB\ThreadProvider_Raven.cs:line 90
   at Scraper.DT_Category.Download() in c:\Users\fm\Desktop\121219scraper-mssql\Scraper\1 (independent)\Download tasks\DT_Category.cs:line 115
   at Scraper.DQ_ParticularForum.QueueReader(Object _this) in c:\Users\fm\Desktop\121219scraper-mssql\Scraper\1 (independent)\DQ_ParticularForum.cs:line 72
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
  InnerException:
```

QUERY:

```
using (var context = new Model.MsSql.Context())
{ 
    var t = context.Threads.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ForumId == (short)forum && s.ExternalId == (int)item);
    ...
}
```

MODEL:

```
namespace Model.MsSql
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Message> Messages;
        public DbSet<Thread> Threads;
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public int ExternalId;
        public short ForumId;
    }

    public class Thread
    {
        public int ExternalId;
        public short ForumId;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I've missed something obvious but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code where you're trying to query the database.

Comment: Yes, that would certainly make it easier for anyone to help... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

The extension method `context.Threads.FirstOrDefault(predicate)` is actually a simple `static` method: it's the same as `Queryable.FirstOrDefault<Thread>(context.Threads, predicate)`.

In your case, `context.Thread` is `null`, so [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) throws the exception as expected.

You should instantiate your `DbSet<>` properties in the constructor of your `Context`:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        this.Messages = ...
        this.Threads = ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I know that the query shouldn't find anything, the tables are empty. But does context.Thread = null means that the table itself isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

This happends if source is null, in your case the context.Threads is for some reason null, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is my first time using ms sql - I assumed that it was included in visual studio but do I have to install it manually?